# Getting error while deploying ml model using Flask

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, nlp, pickle

Getting below error. Maybe while loading the ML model.

`ValueError: Layer 'embedding' expected 1 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['embedding/embeddings:0']`

Here is the code I wrote to deploy my ML model using Flask.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import numpy as np
import re
from keras.utils.data_utils import pad_sequences
# from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import pickle
import json

import joblib

# Load the model using joblib
model = joblib.load('model.pkl')


app = Flask(__name__)


def tokenizer_from_json(tokenizer_json):
    tokenizer = Tokenizer()
    tokenizer.word_index = tokenizer_json['word_index']
    tokenizer.index_word = {int(i): w for i, w in tokenizer_json['index_word'].items()}
    tokenizer.document_count = tokenizer_json['document_count']
    tokenizer.word_docs = tokenizer_json['word_docs']
    return tokenizer

# with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as file:
#     model = pickle.load(file)

with open('tokenizer.json', 'r') as file:
    tokenizer_json = json.load(file)
tokenizer = tokenizer_from_json(tokenizer_json)

with open('username_mapping.json', 'r') as file:
    username_mapping = json.load(file)

with open('party_mapping.json', 'r') as file:
    party_mapping = json.load(file)

max_sequence_length = 200

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/predicted', methods=['POST'])
def predicted():
    sentence = request.form['sentence']
    
    sentence = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', sentence)
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    tokens = sentence.split()
    tokens_sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([tokens])
    tokens_padded = pad_sequences(tokens_sequence, maxlen=max_sequence_length)
    username_index = np.argmax(model.predict(tokens_padded))
    predicted_username = list(username_mapping.keys())[list(username_mapping.values()).index(username_index)]
    predicted_party = party_mapping.get(predicted_username, 'Unknown Party')
    
    return render_template('predicted.html', party=predicted_party)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Is there any way to resolve this bug?

I tried loading model in all form like pickle, h5, joblib.

PS: user_mapping and party_mapping are some python dictionaries while I had saved as json files to load them while writing flask code.

Comment: example of `.pkl` file please ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?